# Run tIme 1004 error in VBA for dynamic formula pasting

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Want to place the given formula in 5 cells

```
'////j and p have been declared before as Double
For j = 5 To 9
p=j*4    

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 5 + (3 * n) + 1 ).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(ROW(RC[p])<255,""DATA N/A"",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(RC[p])-250,COLUMN(RC[p]),,,))/RC[p]-1),""DATA N/A"")"

Next j
```

There is a Run Time 1004 error in the ActiveCell.... line . I am unable to debug the error. Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually want the string 'p' to appear in your formula. I've no idea if your formula is valid btw.

```
Sub x()

Dim j As Long, p As Long, n As Long

For j = 5 To 9
    p = j * 4
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 5 + (3 * n) + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(ROW(RC[" & p & "])<255,""DATA N/A"",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(RC[" & p & "])-250,COLUMN(RC[" & p & "]),,,))/RC[" & p & "]-1),""DATA N/A"")"
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes I dont want the string 'p' but its value in the formulae , your edit is not working.

Comment: "Not working" is not a helpful response. As I said, have you checked that your formula is syntactically correct?

Comment: ,Sir, I want to edit this vba code which I have generated by recording a macro, hence syntactically this  shall be correct , Please suggest what to do .   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(ROW(RC[-13])<255,""DATA   
 N/A"",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(RC[-13])-250,COLUMN(RC[-13]),,,))/RC[-13]-1),""DATA N/A"")"

Comment: Here instead of '-13' I want a to place different values of p in different cells.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? An error message, or unexpected results? In your loop, p will only have the values 20, 24, 28, 32, and 36. It will never be -13. Also have you declared 'n'?

Comment: "Not working" meant , it was still giving an error and code didn't work. Sir, I want to place 20,24,28,32 and 36 in place of -13 for 5 different cells ; i.e why I am using a loop. While recording the macro I used a column which was 13 columns left to the concerned-cell, but now I want to use different columns for 5 other cells which are on right side of the cells. Is there any other way to do it? It will be of great help.

Comment: Yes I have declared ' n ' as Double

Comment: I've edited the code above, and it runs for me without an error. I can't see what is different so I don't know why you are getting an error. Can you try again and let me know how you get on?

Comment: Good. Perhaps you'd like to accept it as an answer and do the same for your previous questions? That's how this place works.